# Pass an undetermined number of object properties that may be nested

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I'm trying to write a handlebars helper where I can pass a JSON string that needs to be parsed, and then grab any specific property, not knowing how many levels of nesting there may be, for example:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper 'parseJSON', (string, properties) ->
    json = JSON.parse string
    # how can I do: return json[oneProperty][andANestedProperty]
```

then with 'responseBody' as my JSON string, not sure how to pass it in, but the idea is I have something like:

```
{{parseJSON responseBody [oneProperty][andANestedProperty] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to say things like:

```
{{parseJSON json 'p1' 'p2'}}
{{parseJSON json 'p1' 'p2' 'p3'}}
```

in your template then you just need to make your helper accept any number of arguments. The only tricky thing is that the Handlebars `properties` argument is always last. This is actually pretty easy using a [CoffeeScript splat](http://coffeescript.org/#splats):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper 'parseJSON', (json, path..., properties) ->
    # path will be an array in here
```

That will give you things like `['p1', 'p2']` and `['p1', 'p2', 'p3']` in the `path` array inside your helper.